# Laravel. How to select entries for the last day

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a message table with the fields id, message and added_on (TIMESTAMP).
It has records for different days.
How to select all entries for the last day only?

Comment: Message::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()])->get();

Comment: @Indra, whereBetween will be significantly slower with dates.

Comment: @Jerodev true, but if you have the database setup correctly with indexes it should not be a big issue, plus technically if you do this often enough and have a large enough database you could use unixtimestamp. It's a longer discussion depending on the solution. And they might want to see entries just from yesterday or 2 days ago so then they could do this or chnage your solution to add another where.

Comment: Are you wanting to get entries for the last 24 hours or entries for "yesterday"?

Comment: No, it's not 24. The last day is not necessarily yesterday, it could be 5 days ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Carbon` to get the last day timestamp and make a query like this:

```
Message::where('added_on', '>', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDay())->get();
```

Assuming you have a model called Message

-- EDIT

So look for `added_on` date to be between the closest day to today in the past, and today. It seems a bit complex, but it works.

```
Message::whereRaw('added_on between
 (select date(added_on) from messages where added_on < current_date()
  order by added_on desc limit 1) and now()')->get();
```

-- EDIT

SQLite 3 version:

```
Message::whereRaw('added_on between (select date(added_on) from messages 
                   where added_on < current_date order by added_on desc limit 1)
                   and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')->get();
```

Comment: Messages for the last day that is in the database are not necessarily yesterday, it could be 5 days ago or 10

Comment: @MyNick then you need to reformat your question. If you want to get all the last messages from every user, then you can sort by date descending and group by the user.

Comment: No, you just need all the messages for the last day that is in the database. For example, the database has messages for 2019-02-03 and 2019-02-06. You need to select all messages for 2019-02-06. And today 2019-02-09

Comment: @MyNick I edited my answer. I tested the results on one of my tables, and it showed what you expect. I hope I understood your problem, and hope it helps.

Comment: I get an error: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "(": syntax error (SQL: select * from "messages" where added_on between
 (select date(added_on) from messages where added_on < current_date()
  order by added_on desc limit 1) and now())"

Comment: By the way i use SQLite 3 database

Comment: @MyNick please make sure that you mention such details when you ask the question at first in order to receive better results. Please take a look at my edit. I hope that this will work now, I tried it on an online editor, hope it works for you. If not at least I hope I gave you an idea on how to solve it. So you should take it from here.

Comment: Thank you very much, nakov!
Your request is working.
Sorry I forgot to specify the database immediately.
I choose your answer best.